# Php file is downloaded when Php program is run in browser

Tags: php7

When I try to run a php program in the browser the php file is  downloaded instead of executed.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to have a web server that executes the php script. PHP is a server side language.

On ubuntu this may be done with apache:

```
 sudo apt-get install apache2 libapache2-mod-php7.0
```

Should set you up with apache.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-16-04 provides more information on how to set it up properly, including where to place the content to be served.